# Small Fuse for 600VDC with 6kA interrupt current

Tags: batteries, components, fuses, high-current, electric-vehicle

I'm looking for a 0.1A - 1A Fuse for a 600VDC system with an interrupt current rating of at least 6kA.

I found some fuses like the TC-632414, which would fulfil the criteria, but they are quite big.

Do you know of any smaller fuses or is this physically impossible?

Comment: Really important to state if this is 600 VDC or VAC.

Comment: I'd say for DC (requiring an extinguishing agent) and a 6kA interrupt rating it's unlikely that you will find a fuse that's much smaller than your example.  That's just based on my experience, so you may yet find something.

Comment: I think you're going to have a hard time finding anything less, short of a customized semiconductor solution that will have many more compromises.